# How do I set text colour in jquery DataTables html5 excel export?

Tags: datatables, export-to-excel

I'm using the jquery DataTables html5 excel export to export a table, if the contents of a particular cell in column I include "Assess" I want the cell text to be set to red. It's easy enough to set cell background:

```
$('row c[r^="I"] ', sheet).each( function () {
  var str= $( this).text();
  if(str.includes("Assess")){
      $(this).attr( 's', '10' );
  } 
})
```

However there's no attribute to set text colour, is there a workaround for this?

(interestingly enough although attribute 10 should give a red background it in fact exports as green!)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can not specify your own color you can only use options mentioned here
https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5